# Blazor: Found markup element with unexpected name 'EditForm' in server side

Tags: blazor, webassembly

I've asked this question in another forum and didn't get a useful answer.

Running VS2019 16.8.0, .Net SDK from 3.1.302 to 5.0.100 - Blazor Server project

I have a razor form and the compiler does not recognize 'EditForm', 'InputText' etc.

Here is the code:

```
page "/GetCustomerProfile"
@using QuoteBL.Data
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<h1>Please fill out form</h1>

<EditForm Model="srcfields" OnValidSubmit="@InvokeGetQuote">

    <p>
        <label for="age">Age:</label>
        <InputText id="age" @bind-Value="QuoteBLModel.age1" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="smoke">Do you smoke?</label>
        <InputCheckbox id="smoke" @bind-Value="AllFieldsModel.smoker" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <label>
            Sex:
            <InputSelect @bind-Value="QuoteBLModel.sex1">
                <option value="Select Sex"></option>
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
            </InputSelect>
        </label>
    </p>

</EditForm>

<div>
    <span id="resultjson"></span>
</div>

@code {

    private AllFieldsModel scrfields = new AllFieldsModel();

    private async Task InvokeGetQuote()
    {

// await etc...

    }
}
```

The model has 2 classes:

```
namespace QuoteBL.Models
{
    public class QuoteBLModel
    {
        public static string productLine = "QoLFlexTerm";
        public static string display = "101";
        public static string state = "";
        public static string sex1 = "";
        public static string age1 = "";
        public static string face_Amount = "";
        public static string premMode = "3";
        public static string flatAmount1 = "0";
        public static string tableRating1 = "0";
        public static string command = "submit";
    }
    public class AllFieldsModel
    {
        public static string CustPhone = "";
        public static string CustEmail = "";
        public static string age1 = "";
        public static string sex1 = "";
        public static string state = "";
        public static bool   smoker = false;
        public static string name = "";
        public static string address = "";
        public static string city = "";
        public static string state = "";
        public static string zip = "";
        public static string loan = "";
        public static string agentPhone = "";
        public static string agentEmail = "";
}
```

The one answer that I got asked me about the `_imports.razor` and I already had the `@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms` in the file.

Not sure where to go for help. Can't figure out what is wrong.

If anyone that stumbles here has a suggestion of where I should be posting this. I would appreciate

Comment: Post the  _imports.razor file, completely. It could hold the syntax error. There is nothing obviously wrong with the code here.

Comment: If your code works even tough the syntax is marked as wrong, it might be [this error](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17660). I also had this "bug" several times, but could not find a proper way to solve it.

Answer (score 5):

Close visual studio and re-run it as administrator. Sometimes even a restart is needed. But if you have used the namespace the project should be build successfully even if it does not recognize components. And also remove static from your properties (that would be your next problem).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with nAviD also you shuld install and import the package

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
```